# Installation of Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Developer Edition fails with unknown property

Tags: windows-vista, sql-server-2008-r2, installation

Installing MS SQL Server 2008 Developer edition on a Vista Ultimate 64 Bit machine keeps returning the following error message:

> #### SQL Server Setup failure
>
> SQL Server Setup has encountered the following error:
> Unknown property.

I've tried the following:

- Uninstalled the previous installation
- Deleted all folders that were installed and had to do with SQL Server 2008
- Cleared my registry using ccleaner
- Tried 'fixit' utility from Microsoft uninstalling left overs

I'm totally out of ideas.

Comment: To determine the cause of error messages like these, it can be helpful to record every action an application performs, using [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645). [This article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2012/01/05/3473797.aspx) is an example of how it can be applied.

Comment: the setup already records everything to a log file. I can't make up anything out of it. But i did give it a shot, that PM software eats my memory totally out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just installed sql server 2012. That went flawless. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

Check registry branch HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Installer\Products\ and remove any SQL Server related entries (e.g. D30CF9A3586C138449FCE4FD3D474979) if exists.

Comment: I have removed some of those product codes a few weeks back. I couldn't find this one in the register. But i did found some SQL Server related stuff. Thought i removed them all. But it still gives me that unknown property error :(